# How to submit a form in Python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to submit a form in Python requests. I'm trying to get the list of all members of my organisation from the website.

I've tried the following code:

```
    searchparams={'name':'smith', 'grade':'0', 'format':'html'}
    r=requests.post('http://www.thewebsite.co.uk/members/dir/search', data=searchparams)
```

but it just returns the HTML of the search screen, not the results.

There are also a bunch of other options I could select, but these are the only ones I care about - do I need to submit values for them all?

The form HTML is below, for you information.

```
    <form method="post" action="/members/dir/search" class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Surname:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="form-control"  />        
            <div class="note">Leave blank to search for all surnames</div>    
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="grade">Grade:</label>
            <select name="grade" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">ALL</option>
                <option value="G6">Grade&nbsp;6</option>
                <option value="G7">Grade&nbsp;7</option>
            </select>    
        </div>  
        <label>Results format:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="format">HTML</label> <input class="tick" type="radio" name="format" value="html" checked="checked"  />
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="format">Excel</label> <input class="tick" type="radio" name="format" value="excel" />
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="format">CSV</label> <input class="tick" type="radio" name="format" value="csv" />
        </div>   
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-danger">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: “do I need to submit values for them all?” — that's site-specific; it depends on how it validates the input. The only way to know if to try with all of them.

Comment: Try grabbing the HTTP traffic using a browser's develop-tools. This should tell you what exactly is sent, and then try & mimic that.

Comment: You need to include the values of the input fields that the user has provided as well as any defaults (depending on how your back-end is written).

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I'll try that later!